# Need to Printing Postgresql database console

Tags: postgresql

Postgresql database store procedure insert query and i need print the raise 
notice the input values

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION new(pk character varying, u character varying,ps character varying)
      RETURNS SETOF record AS
    $BODY$
    BEGIN


    RAISE NOTICE 'PK is %','--'pk;
    RAISE NOTICE 'Username is %','--'u;
    RAISE NOTICE 'Password is %','--'ps;

    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO table_sp("pk_id","username","password")VALUES ('''||pk||''' ,'''||u||''','''||ps||''')' ;


    END;
    $BODY$
      LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
      COST 100
      ROWS 1000;
    ALTER FUNCTION new(character varying, character varying,character varying)
      OWNER TO postgres;
```

UserManualInputs:

```
select new('2','admin','admin');
```

I gave the manual input through `select new('2','admin','admin')` and i need print in PostgreSQL console input values using raise notice like `(RAISE NOTICE 'PK is %','--'pk)`

Comment: Please always mention your PostgreSQL version in questions.

Answer (score 2):

Craig Ringer replied to you, but I have to attach a notice.

Using dynamic SQL (EXECUTE statement) in your example is very wrong idea, and badly implementation too.

- use simply SQL statement only. Use dynamic SQL only if you needed!

```
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE '...';
  INSERT INTO table_sp(pk_id, username, password)
    VALUES(pk, u, ps);
END;
```

- you used a antipattern - your code is SQL injection vulnerable. Depends on PostgreSQL version that you use, you can use a more patterns how to write secure code:

```
  -- very old (but secure, and more readable)
  EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO table_sp (pk_id, username, password) VALUES ('
             quote_literal(pk) || ',' quote_literal(u) || ',' || quote_literal(ps) || ')';

  -- little bit modern (8.4) - secure, readable, and fast
  EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO table_sp (pk_id, username, password) VALUES($1,$2,$3)'
    USING pk, u, ps

  -- or modern (but USING clause is better and faster for this use case)
  EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO table_sp(pk_id, username, password) VALUES(%L,%L,%L)',
             pk, u, ps)
```

You newer can write code:

```
-- very very very bad code!!!!!
EXECUTE 'some statement ''' || variable || ''' some other ';
```

sorry for offtopic.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it. SQL injection is never off-topic. I ignored everything after the `RAISE` as irrelevant noise for the purpose of the question and didn't notice the horror that followed. BTW, I typically use `EXECUTE format('insert into %I (%I) values ($1)', tablename, colname) USING value`; that way you get to use `format`'s smart identifier formatting and still get the parameterization offered by `EXECUTE ... USING`.

Comment: @CraigRinger yes, a example of format in my answer is unnatural - warped for mentioned use case. Function "format" is designed exactly for usage described by you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by "PostgreSQL console" you mean `psql`, just make sure you `SET client_min_messages = 'notice'` or higher.

Your syntax probably doesn't do what you expect, though. Demonstrating using `DO` instead of full functions to keep things brief and simple:

```
regress=> DO
$$
DECLARE
    pk integer := 4;
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'PK is %','--'pk;
END;
$$;
NOTICE:  PK is --
DO
```

Maybe you wanted:

```
regress=> DO
$$
DECLARE
    pk integer := 4;
BEGIN
    RAISE NOTICE 'PK is --%',pk;
END;
$$;
NOTICE:  PK is --4
DO
```

?

Beware that such messages will also get logged to the PostgreSQL system log files, so you should not reveal passwords in such messages in a production app.

BTW, `new` is a really bad name choice for a function; I suggest something that isn't a keyword in most languages [including SQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html).

Comment: ok this manually printed 4. but i need to print (front end value or user inputs)passing parameter in RAISE NOTICE 'PK is --%',pk;

Comment: @Kannan Of course. I'm just demonstrating the syntax of `RAISE NOTICE`; the same thing will work in your function. `DO` is PL/PgSQL, just like `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION`.

Comment: ok i got it, but its not printing get parameter through front end value in RAISE NOTICE.

Comment: @Kannan I'd need to see the full code including any schema definitions etc required to run it, then. Maybe pop it on http://sqlfiddle.com/ ? (SQLFiddle won't show NOTICEs, but it's a good way to make sure the code is self-contained and complete).